# Responsive design - background strech to left

Tags: css, responsive-design

I can't figured out a background problem. I want my logo and text background to strech to left, but the text has to stay in the main wrap.

thank you!

[image]

Comment: Do you have any html/css to share?

Comment: Yes we would prefer to see code. I know what I do to make my backgrounds responsive, but this may not be what you want/need - and we can't do it all for you :)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late, i played with media screen and width. Now its good for the customer. 
On the top "PRÉMIUM ÖNKISZOLGÁLÓ AUTÓMOSÓ" background. and the logo black line.
http://redcarspa.hu/